# Problems to get a integer value from an input

Tags: php, html, json

Good night, I receive data from a form via POST, and I would like some fields of this input to be as integer, and when I give a:

```
var_dump($_POST)
```

It returns all data as String, enclosed in double quotes (which is what I need remove).

Basically what I needed is remove double quotes from some fields, but without having to create a variable that receives what came from POST , I would like in the controller just work with the array that I receive from POST, for example:

```
$var = json_encode($_POST);
```

An example of json I would need would be something like this:

```
$json_str = '{"name":"Jason", "age":38}';
```

and what comes would be

```
$json_str = '{"name":"Jason", "age":"38"}';
```

I tried the input number but it returns the value with double quotes too

```
<form method="POST" action="mypage.php>
<input type="number" name="number"/>
</form>
```

I could do like this:

```
$var = intval($_POST['number'])
```

But I'd like to work without creating variables, only with $_POST which is my form inside an array;

These quotes get in my way when converting the array into JSON, because in JSON some fields if I send them with quotes error, I tried to convert everything to integer fields with `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK`, but the Strings give an error because they go without the quotes

If you've come across this, can someone show me the way

Comment: This isn't possible. The format that post data is sent in has no way to distinguish between integers and strings. It's just `key=value&key=value` and all values are treated as strings.

Comment: If you don't want another variable, you can assign back to `$_POST` `$_POST['number'] = intval($_POST['number'])`

Comment: Yeah, it's a way, but i'd like to build a generic controller for use to any form, with 4, 5 10, 20 fields with different names. There's another way, maybe with ajax that can I follow ?

Comment: You can send JSON if you use AJAX in the client. But JSON doesn't go into `$_POST`, you need to use `json_decode(file_get_value('php://input'))`

Comment: ok, I'm gonna try this, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you start receiving the POST data, use helper functions like [`intval($_POST['age']`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.intval.php)) to convert your input into an integer.

If you have a boolean: [`boolval($_POST['condition'])`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.boolval.php)

These functions return values you can work with. Consider checking your number with [`is_numeric($_POST['age'])`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.is-numeric) to verify you received a number.

Of course there are plenty of other stuff you could do to make sure your input is clean.

Using the [`filter_var()`](https://www.php.net/function.filter-var) function and for example the `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT` php filter constant you can sanitize the string.

Probably there are other measurements you could take but I am not the php pro to know this stuff. Modern php frameworks will mostly take care of all this.

Comment: He knows he can call `intval()`, he says he doesn't want to do that.

Comment: Well, how on earth should you solve this problem otherwise?

Comment: As I said in my comment, I don't think he can with the constraints he specifies.

Comment: I was thinking send my input with the value + an string like 'test', and after use json_encode() and JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK, I'll use an String replace to throw away the string 'test' and left only the value with double quotes, it isn't the better away but probably works